# Cannot properly execute copy() function in Perl Script through PHP

Tags: php, perl

I am a complete beginner in Perl. Suppose I have this PHP and Perl Script that copies a file into its directory after renaming it:

PHP:

```
<?php
exec("perl /home/me/Desktop/my.pl 2>&1");
?>
```

Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Copy;
chdir("/home/me/Desktop");
copy("file1.txt", "file2.txt") or die "File cannot be copied.";
```

This code works when called using Terminal (either calling `my.pl` using `perl ~/Desktop/my.pl` or calling the php file using `php /var/www/sample.php`).

However, it does not work when I load the php file through a browser using `localhost/sample.php`. And I am sure there are no problems with Apache.

Can anyone explain what is happening, and what should be done to get the desired results?

Comment: Check your web server logs, it should give you hints. Its mostly due to webserver run as different user and don't(shouldn't) have permission to write to your home directory.

Comment: Yes, I did get that 'Permission denied' earlier. How do I fix that? I tried using `chmod 755` on the file to be copied, I still get the same result.

Comment: So then go learn about [Unix permissions](http://enwp.org/Filesystem_permissions), and apply your new knowledge. You don't just "fix" it as there is nothing *wrong* per se; you must understand the concept and make decisions accordingly, and no one here can relieve you of the decisions because only you know the details of your computer and how you intend to use it and how security applies to it. Even an introductory explanation would be out of proportion as a Stack Overflow comment or answer, and unsuited to this site.